# Setting app pool identify for kestrel web server hosted on Linux container

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, kestrel-http-server

When using IIS, we can set application pool identity (see the below image). I am running my ASP.NET Core 3.1 application on Linux container which runs on top of OpenShift. How can I set the app pool identify (account under which the application will run) for application running on kestrel web server ?

**I want to run process under specific service account**

[image]

Comment: App pools are an IIS thing, you won't have one if you are running kestrel directly it will run as whatever you start the process as.

Comment: @Crowcoder: So if I am running kestrel using a container (based on Linux image) which is running on OpenShift, how can i set the identity for the process ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with open shift.

Answer (score 0):

I believe down deep OpenShift is using Docker containers. In docker you have

```
docker run -it \
--user $UID:$GID \
```

Of course,  this will probably need to be expressed in a Kubernetes YAML file, which has a section for the pod definition like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsGroup: 3000
    fsGroup: 2000
```